# awk: how to use variable as a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, formatting

I have file in a format:

```
==============================
nfsserver1.example.com
==============================
/vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
/vol/vol2   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10

==============================
nfsserver3.example.com
==============================

==============================
nfsserver4.example.com
==============================
/vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
```

and I need to reformat it to this:

```
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol1    -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol2    -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1    -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
```

This is what I tried:

```
while read server; do
    echo "---- ${server} -----------------------------------------"
    cat file.txt|\
        grep -v "========"|\
        awk -v srv=${server} '/^nfsserver1\.example\.com$/ {f=1} f; /^$/ {f=0}'|\
        grep -v "^$"|\
        awk -v srv=${server} '{printf("%s %s\n",srv,$0)}'
    echo
    server=""
done < <(cat file.txt|grep "^[a-z].*\.example\.com$")
```

but I do not know how exactly I can incorporate variable into a pattern search.
I tried this:

```
awk -v srv=${server} '$0 ~ srv {f=1} f; /^$/ {f=0}'
```

But it produces incorrect output and I would like to have exact match with the variable.

```
---- nfsserver1.example.com -----------------------------------------
nfsserver1.example.com nfsserver1.example.com
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol1    -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol2    -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol1 -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol2 -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver1.example.com nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1 -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10

---- nfsserver3.example.com -----------------------------------------
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1 -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10

---- nfsserver4.example.com -----------------------------------------
nfsserver4.example.com nfsserver4.example.com
nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1    -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
nfsserver4.example.com nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1 -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10

---- nfsserver3.example.com -----------------------------------------
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver3.example.com nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1 -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
```

Lots of lines that I do not need. I am not quite sure where they come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    NF==1 && /[^=]/ { srvr=$0; done=0 }
    NF==2 { print srvr, $0; done=1 }
    !NF && !done { print srvr }
    END{ if (!done) print srvr }
' file
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol2   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver3.example.com
nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
```

All the extra output you were getting is because you called awk multiple times and wrapped the calls in a shell loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v RS='==+\n' \
'/^nfsserver/{ k = $1; n = NR + 1 }
 NR == n{ 
     gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/, "", $0);
     len = split($0, a, "\n");
     if (!len) len = 1;
     for (i=1; i<=len; i++) print k, a[i]
}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver1.example.com /vol/vol2   -sec=sys,rw=clinet1,root=clinet10
nfsserver3.example.com 
nfsserver4.example.com /vol/vol1   -sec=sys,rw=clinet4,root=clinet10
```